# Error 400 on SERVER: custom functions must be called with a single array that contains the arguments

Tags: puppet

I've installed a jboss module for Puppet cloned from this repo: https://github.com/example42/puppet-jboss, but when I run puppet agent -t --trace I'm getting this error "Error 400 on SERVER: custom functions must be called with a single array that contains the arguments"

Here is the full trace http://pastebin.com/YBJ289Tw

Amazon Linux, Ruby 1.8.7, Puppet 3.0.1
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that Puppi module on PuppetForge wasn't up to date. I updated to the last version from GitHub (https://github.com/example42/puppi), restarted Puppet master and it worked just fine !